# Cannot do simple task on ec2 spark cluster from local pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I am trying to execute pyspark from my mac to do compute on a EC2 spark cluster.
If I login to the cluster, it works as expected:

```
$ ec2/spark-ec2 -i ~/.ec2/spark.pem -k spark login test-cluster2
$ spark/bin/pyspark
```

Then do a simple task

```
>>> data=sc.parallelize(range(1000),10)`
>>> data.count()
```

Works as expected:

```
14/06/26 16:38:52 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: count at <stdin>:1
14/06/26 16:38:52 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at <stdin>:1) with 10 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
14/06/26 16:38:52 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0 (count at <stdin>:1)
...
14/06/26 16:38:53 INFO spark.SparkContext: Job finished: count at <stdin>:1, took 1.195232619 s
1000
```

But now if I try the same thing from local machine,

```
$ MASTER=spark://ec2-54-234-204-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 bin/pyspark
```

it can't seem to connect to the cluster

```
14/06/26 09:45:43 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://ec2-54-234-204-13.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077...
14/06/26 09:45:47 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
...
  File "/Users/anthony1/git/incubator-spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.collect.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted: Spark cluster looks down
14/06/26 09:53:17 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

I thought the problem was in the ec2 security but it does not help even after adding inbound rules to both master and slave security groups to accept all ports.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Others are asking same question on mailing list
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Deploying-a-python-code-on-a-spark-EC2-cluster-td4758.html#a8465

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spark-ec2 script configure the Spark Cluster in EC2 as standalone, which mean it can not work with remote submits. I've been struggled with this same error you described for days  before figure out it's not supported. The message error is unfortunately incorrect.

So you have to copy your stuff and log into the master to execute your spark task.

Comment: Recently I started to work in a sbt plugin to workaround this limitation. https://github.com/felixgborrego/sbt-spark-ec2-plugin

Comment: Somehow I missed your response Felix.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my experience `Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory` usually means you have accidentally set the cores too high, or set the executer memory too high - i.e. higher than what your nodes actually have.

Other, less likely causes, could be you got the URI wrong and your not really connecting to the master. And once I saw that problem when the `/run` partition was 100%.

Even less likely, your cluster may actually be down, and you need to restart your spark workers.

Comment: Thanks samthebest.  First and third do not seem to be the cause because I can execute the task as expected if submitted from the master node itself.  So the cluster is definitely working.  On the second reason, it's probably not that either because I did intentionally put in a wrong URI for test and got a different error.  In fact, tail -f on the master node log also shows corresponding errors

Comment: try running df -h and df -i on all your nodes (long shot).